# Wine: Trying to Play Command & Conquer 1, Freezing

Tags: wine, games, freeze

I'm trying to play [C&C 1](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4891) on [Wine](https://winehq.com) 4.0.3.  The game screen freezes periodically, forcing me to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the game and end it hard via the System Monitor.  Though I still have sound effects in the background, and can hear stuff happening,  I just can't see anything, as the screen does not update.

I'm running the game through [Lutris](https://lutris.net/), and have to save every 5 minutes, in case the game freezes.

I set the game to run under XP compatibility.

I found [a thread](https://answers.ea.com/t5/C-C-The-Ultimate-Collection/Tiberian-Sun-freezes-up-at-main-menu/td-p/2400427) about something similar happening under Windows 8.  Apparently it stopped after the user used XP compatibility mode, and set the display to limit to 16 bit graphics.  Is that possible under Wine?